# Face Recognizer OpenCV C++ (VS)

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm not sure if I call this a problem or not but I'm trying to use Face Recognizer from OpenCV tutorial and it works fine.

> Steps:
>   1) load CSV (file containing the path of all image) and train the
>   algorithm.
>
> 2) load the xml file for face detection (Haar Cascade)
>
> 3) open camera and crop the face
>
> 4) predtect

It works fine when I use a familiar face but when show another face I mean, unknown face, it should give me an (-1) for an unknown face, but it gives me an approximation or the closest face label.
I know it suppose to work like that, it's about proximity for that they put a threshold, but I can't set it , I'm using OpenCV 3.1, I know that because I set the num_components and the threshold in the creation methode:

```
int num_components = 10;
double threshold = 10.0;    
Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createEigenFaceRecognizer(num_components,threshold );

printf("thresh= %d", model->getThreshold());
```

it gives me 0 ,even when I use 0 and 0.0 , it's the same, and I never get (-1), and they are no set("thersh",val) methode in this version.

any ideas or correct me if I'm getting things wrong
thank you in advance.

Comment: Quit using `printf` and use `std::cout`.  I don't know what variable type `getThreshold` returns, but if it isn't an `int`, your program's behavior is undefined due to a format specifier mismatch (`%d`).  Using `std::cout` prevents these types of mistakes.

Comment: %d stand for double, and thresh return double
but the problem is not there, i'm asking why i can't get -1 when i give him and unknown face.

Comment: @shadow No, `%d` does not stand for _double_. Read some [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Comment: @shadow.  A double's format specifier is `%lf`, not `%d`.  Your code has undefined behavior, so it makes no sense to go any further until you fix that error (and ideally, by using `std::cout`).  We have no idea if you've wasted your time all because of this silly mistake.

Comment: You might be receiving a compiler warning about this.  It's not required, but some compilers are scanning the format string and matching it with the inputs.

Comment: new update:
sorry for my mistake about %d it means decimal i guess not double, anyway, i just used cout as  @PaulMcKenzie said and it shows me what i want, i just use it to display  the threshold nothing more.
what i did next is changing the CSV file and i start the count from 1 not from 0, and it seems the unknown face's label is 0 and not -1. i'm not sure this but this is what i get :/
i just need someone who correct me, because the documentation of opencv say  the unknow sface label is -1,